# C# Adding copied data to Google sheets.

Tags: c#

I am a fairly new programmer but want to start working on a useful program. I am familiar with what APIs are used for and I have looked at Google sheets APIs but I can't find what I am looking for. I want to copy some text from a website (3 words) and click a button to add this text to a Google sheet (3 cells) in the same row. Could someone help point me in the right direction??

Answer (score 0):

Well its a very high level question. you can create a add-ons or plugins to do this.
To start with read here for directions. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/